# Displaying random text in Vue.js template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple `Loader` component in my Vue.js app that just displays one of messages, randomly. I did it like that:

```js
Vue.component('Loader', {
    data() {
        const textEntries = [
            'Just a second',
            'Please wait',
            'Almost there',
            'And there we go',
        ];

        return {
            text: textEntries[Math.trunc(Math.random() * textEntries.length)]
        };
    },
    template: '<p class="loading">{{ text }}...</p>'
});
```

I'm not sure if keeping this in `data` like that is fine. Won't my text ever get re-rendered with another text? Also, having the array in the `data()` method seems awkward. Would it be more suitable to use lifecycle hooks for that instead? Or computed property?

Comment: Please mark an answer as the solution for future visitors who face such an issue.

Comment: I don't like any of the answers so far.

Comment: What's missing from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the lifecycle hooks which `Vue` provides. More precisely, I believe that for your example, you should use the `created` hook. So your code will be like this:

```js
Vue.component('Loader', {
    created: function () {
        this.$options.textEntries = [
            'Just a second',
            'Please wait',
            'Almost there',
            'And there we go',
        ];

        this.$options.randomIndex = Math.trunc(Math.random() * textEntries.length);
    },
    data() {
        return {
            text: this.$options.textEntries[this.$options.randomIndex]
        };
    },
    template: '<p class="loading">{{ text }}...</p>'
});
```

If you leave `textEntries` within the `data Vue property`, then you will not have access to it as it will be erased from the memory as soon as the `data function` is processed.

**WARNING: The `$options`, which I am using, cannot be changed since it is read-only. For more information, I would redirect you to [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options).**

Answer (score 0):

As I know data() will called only once, so the text will be one of the `textEntries`

I think it's better to extract `textEntries` out of the data method(since it will not be changed, so it should not be generated each `data()` call.

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to define the array in `data` and get the random text as `computed`:

```js
new Vue({
     el:"#app",
     data() {
        return{
          textEntries: [
            'Just a second',
            'Please wait',
            'Almost there',
            'And there we go',
          ]
        }
    },
    computed:{
         text: function(){
              return this.textEntries[Math.trunc(Math.random() * this.textEntries.length)]
         }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <p class="loading">{{ text }}...</p>
</div>
```

If you want the text to be re-rendered every period of time, you can use `setTimeout` and keep track of the random index:

```js
new Vue({
     el:"#app",
     data() {
        return{
          textEntries: [
            'Just a second',
            'Please wait',
            'Almost there',
            'And there we go',
          ],
          index: 0
        }
    },
    mounted(){
         setInterval(function(){
              this.index = Math.trunc(Math.random() * this.textEntries.length)
         }.bind(this), 3000);
    },
    computed:{
         text: function(){
              return this.textEntries[this.index];
         }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <p class="loading">{{ text }}...</p>
</div>
```